# What's the difference between writeList and writeTypedList in Android Parcelable

Tags: android

I'm having problems reading out a list of custom objects.
wirteList/readList is giving the Unmarshelling unknown type code exception, but wirteTyped/readTypedList works fine .
According to the API doc.

- writeList uses writeValue to write values, and writeValue accepts Any object that implements the Parcelable protocol and List itself.

If that is the case, why writeList won't work with custom objects.
My object is implementing Parcelable of course.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@a7d7d2: Unmarshalling unknown type code 6881395 at offset 488
09-28 10:58:01.432  9449  9449 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2319)
09-28 10:58:01.432  9449  9449 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2592)
09-28 10:58:01.432  9449  9449 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
09-28 10:58:01.432  9449  9449 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.BaseBundle.getStringArrayList(BaseBundle.java:1038)
09-28 10:58:01.432  9449  9449 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Bundle.getStringArrayList(Bundle.java:908)
09-28 10:58:01.432  9449  9449 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityTransitionState.readState(ActivityTransitionState.java:133)
09-28 10:58:01.432  9449  9449 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6238)
09-28 10:58:01.432  9449  9449 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
09-28 10:58:01.432  9449  9449 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe because of your `Custom Object`. You should post it here. Sometimes, you must set `ClassLoader` before reading value from intent to avoid `BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling`:

```
intent.setExtrasClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
// reading value here: intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra()
```

Comment: Hi, that class is too big. I can't really post it here. Basically, I was using writeList and readList (List outVal, ClassLoader loader), I have supplied the classLoader by using ABC.class.getclassloader(). But still it only works with readTypedList (List<T> list, Creator<T> c).

Comment: @WenChao you should post your `Error Log` from `LogCat` for more error detail. Maybe ppl can help you from that log cat

Comment: Edited, I don't think the log here is very helpful.

Comment: @WenChao You should check your `Creator` field 1st, then check `writeToParcel` and your `Constructor(in)`. Maybe the problem is when you write and read different type of fields.